# With the Mediawiki API, how can we fetch a version of a Wikipedia page other than the latest?

Tags: mediawiki-api

The [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) can be used to fetch Wikipedia pages. In the docs, they only show how to fetch the latest version of a page. However, I know that Wikipedia stores every version of every page. Is there a way to access those other versions through the MediaWiki API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are going to retrieve https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=5585818 .

One can retrieve older versions:

1. as [wikitext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikitext) format using:

   1. [prop=revisions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) + (`rvstart`/`rvend` or `rvstartid`/`rvendid` parameters):
      https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Project:Sandbox&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&rvstartid=5585818&rvlimit=1
   2. [index.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Raw) + (`action=raw` and `oldid` parameters):
      https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=5585818&action=raw
2. as HTML using:

   1. [action=parse](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) together with `oldid` parameter:
      https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=parse&oldid=5585818&prop=text
   2. [index.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php) + `action=render`. (`action=parse` API is preferred over this method): https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=5585818&acton=render